# Is there any way to call part of the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function, constants

I am calling a function I wrote on an `on click` method. I wanted to know if I can also call part of that function in another `onChange` method.

Or is there any other way to go about it?

My function:

```
const filts = flatten => {
 let new_filts = {
'site': $('#sites select option:selected')[0].value,,
'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
'date': 'date',
'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
'errors': []
 }


if (new_filts.site.length === 0)
    new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');


 if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
   let message = '';
   new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
   message += `<li>${d}</li>`
  });

 $.confirm({
  title: 'All filts Are Required',
});
}


 if (flatten) {
  new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
 }
   return new_filters;
  }
```

I need the whole function for my on click method which goes at the end like:

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
   filters = filts(true);
});
```

`update` is a button. I want it to call all of the filts function. To check for errors and all.

I have another `onChange` method on the `site`. I was hoping to call the `filts` function here again but I only want to be able to call this part of the function:

```
const filts = flatten => {
 let new_filts = {
'site': 'google',
'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
'date': 'date',
'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
'errors': []
 }

 if (flatten) {
  new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
 }
   return new_filters;
  }
```

my `onchange` function:

```
$('#site').on('change', function() {
   filters = filts(true);
});
```

I dont want to call the error check of my function in my onchange.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Just make it into two functions and call one inside the other (possibly with parameters). Other that than, there are generators, but you definitely do not want them :D

Comment: @Akxe, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass one more parameter that will state either you want to check error or not like this

```
    const filts = flatten, checkError => {
       let new_filts = {
       'site': $('#sites select option:selected')[0].value,,
       'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
       'date': 'date',
       'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
       'errors': []
    }

if(checkError){
  if (new_filts.site.length === 0)
    new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');


 if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
   let message = '';
   new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
      message += `<li>${d}</li>`
   });

  $.confirm({
    title: 'All filts Are Required',
  });
 }
}

 if (flatten) {
  new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
 }
   return new_filters;
  }
```

And then call your method on two different locations like

```
filts(true,true);
```

to check the error

```
filts(true,false);
```

to not check the error

Comment: how do I call this function in my `on click` and `onChange` methods?

Comment: Edited answer please have a look And mark it as solved if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add another argument to the `filts` function to stop executing the further instructions inside the function?

```
$('#update').on('click', function() {
   filters = filts(true, true);
});

$('#site').on('change', function() {
   filters = filts(true, false);
});

const filts = (flatten, shouldContinue) => {
 let new_filts = {
'site': $('#sites select option:selected')[0].value,,
'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
'date': 'date',
'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
'errors': []
 }

if (!shouldContinue) return;

if (new_filts.site.length === 0)
    new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');


 if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
   let message = '';
   new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
   message += `<li>${d}</li>`
  });

 $.confirm({
  title: 'All filts Are Required',
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the common part in its own function, and then call it in your event handlers:

```js
//the common part between the onclick handler and the onchange handler
function commonFunc(flatten) {
  let new_filts = {
  'site': 'google',
  'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
  'date': 'date',
  'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
  'errors': []
  }

  if (flatten) {
    new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
  }
  return new_filts;
}


//the filts function (onclick handler)
const filts = flatten => {

  //call the commonFunc to get value of new_filts
  let new_filts = commonFunc(flatten);

  //do extra stuff with new_filts
  
  if (new_filts.site.length === 0)
      new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');


  if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
    let message = '';
    new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
    message += `<li>${d}</li>`
   });

  $.confirm({
    title: 'All filts Are Required',
  });
}



  
  
$('#site').on('change', function() {
   filters = commonFunc(true);
});


$('#update').on('click', function() {
   filters = filts(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a global variable in the document, It will be work.

```
var globalEventCheck = false; // global variable

$('#update').on('click change', function(e) {
  globalEventCheck = (e.type == 'click') ? true : false;
  filters = filts(true);
});

const filts = flatten => {
  let new_filts = {
    'site': $('#sites select option:selected')[0].value,,
    'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
    'date': 'date',
    'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
    'errors': []
  }
  if (globalEventCheck) { // new condition
   if (new_filts.site.length === 0) {
     new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');
   }
   if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
     let message = '';
     new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
     message += `<li>${d}</li>`
   });

    $.confirm({
      title: 'All filts Are Required',
    });
  } // new condition end

  if (flatten) {
     new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
  }
  return new_filters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you can do that without passing param, you can also pass param for further logic.

```
const filts = () => {

    //console.log(event.data.flatten); get your param value

    let new_filts = {
        'site': $('#sites select option:selected')[0].value,
        'group_by': $('#group_by select option:selected')[0].value,
        'date': 'date',
        'topics': $('#topics select option:selected')[0].value,
        'errors': []
    };

    if (event.type == 'click') {

        if (new_filts.site.length === 0)
            new_filts.errors.push('Please select at least one <b>Site</b>.');

        if (new_filts.errors.length > 0) {
            let message = '';
            new_filts.errors.forEach(d => {
                message += `<li>${d}</li>`
            });

            $.confirm({
                title: 'All filts Are Required',
            });
        }

    }

    if (flatten) {
        new_filts.site = new_filts.site.join('|');
    }

    return new_filters;

}

$('#site').click({ flatten: 'customValue1' }, filts);
$('#update').change({ flatten: 'customValue2' }, filts)
```